# I am developing a Word Web Add-In. What is the recommended way to manage local and deployment versions of the manifest.xml

Tags: office-js, office-addins

While developing on local, the `manifest.xml` has urls that looks like `https://localhost:3000/assets/logo-icon-80.png`. When I deploy the add-in to webserver, those urls needs to look like `https://mydomain/myfolder/assets/logo-32.png`.

I do not want to maintain two different manifest.xml files.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to run it locally (for debugging purposes) you may keep the real server URL in the manifest file. Otherwise, you need to replace the local server URL moniker with a real one before deploying or publishing to the store.

You can use various tools for replacing the URL automatically for you. Try googling over the internet for any convenient editors or tools.